# How is the scope of a site decided?

Tags: support, per-site-meta, help-center, scope

I suppose admins can track down **who** made what edits to the page "What topics can I ask about here?" that every SE site has (example page from [webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)).

Is it also possible to track down **why** certain edits were made, i.e. what the **decision process** was behind defining the scope of each site? For example, does one admin propose an edit (with a justification?), followed by a review process where other admins comment and approve?

**Why I ask**: I'd like to understand the decisions/discussions that went into defining the scope of specific sites. For example (but not limited to) webapps.stackexchange.com

Comment: It's usually on the site's meta. In this case, [meta.Webapps](https://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Mast Any user can express any opinion on the respective site's meta. But my question is about **what the admins do after that**: is there a review process among admins for edits of that page, etc.

Comment: You asked: "I'd like to understand the decisions/discussions that went into defining the scope of specific sites." Those discussions are often on the site's meta (and moderator-chatrooms, of which us mere mortals see no records) and there's usually a discussion before a decision. Often enough the decision is on the meta as well, but this could hugely differ between sites I imagine.

Comment: Having been through it at least twice, it starts in beta and never. ever. ends.

Comment: If you want to find the revision history of that on-topic help page you can use [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/webapps/query/1260806/find-posts-and-the-revisions-of-moderator-only-content). Under posttypeid = 7 a couple of different contenttypes are cobbled together but you can find that text in the query among the texts for the tour and the election page.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85757/946172

Answer (score 5):

Finding when the `help/on-topic` page for a site was edited, and by who, is easy to do for the moderators of that site, because there is a History button that they can see beneath it.

The process of scoping a site will be similar but different for every site.  It will likely involve many formal per-site Meta Q&As and possibly many informal chats.

If you decide which site you wish to investigate, then I recommend starting with that site's Meta, to see if you can uncover when and why a particular part of its scope came about.

If you are seeking to modify the scope of a site then start by asking a question on that site's Meta.

In general, the moderators of a site will only edit the `help/on-topic` page of their site when the community of that site appears to have reached consensus about whether its scope needs to be modified.

As an example of how often the `help/on-topic` page gets edited, I just looked at the one for a 10 years old site that I moderate, and it has only had 8 revisions.

Answer (score 2):

As I already mentioned on Meta Web Applications...

> Maybe you should learn what was the process followed to create Web
> Applications. This should take you to learn about
> https://area51.stackexchange.com/, then to
> https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57?phase=definition

Related [How can I propose a new site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76974/289691)

---

> Besides the link provided in [the other
> answer](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4745/88163), other
> links were "greasemonkey" is mentioned in the context of the site
> scope
>
> - [Is Web Applications still the best stop for bookmarklets?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4580/88163)
> - [The Tour appears to give contradictory advice about browser questions](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3816/88163)
>
> The criteria that I apply is
>
> - If the question is about a user-script that is centered on modify / interact with an specific web application the question might be
>   on-topic
> - If the question is exclusively about the web browser extension (i.e. how to install / uninstall it) the question is off-topic and might be
>   migrated to Super User.
> - If the question is about HTML/CSS/JavaScript and it's not centered on an specific web application it might be migrated to Stack Overflow